# Little black wireframe globes?

Tags: visibility

I'm new to Blender, using 2.78. I choose ALT + H because all my eye icons are mysteriously gone in my Outliner window, and that was supposed to be how you get everything visible again. But now I have all these little black wireframe globes and I don't know how to hide them (not even sure what they are for). How do I get rid of these in my view? Why did my eye icons disappear? My Outliner window does not have a filter button in its top bar, so I can't filter for the things I want to see. :(

[image]

See, no eye icons!

[image]

Comment: Hi, I can't understand what happened to you outliner, it seems it doesn't show anymore control icons (eye but also arrow and camera). Does it happen after restarting blender on e new default (cube) file? I guess those little spheres are controlling shapes, parented to an (invisible) armature bones. Moving them around in pose mode should alter your mesh is armature is correctly set. I guess they were all hidden before. You should be able to select them and hide pressing H? Btw why 2.78? try upgrade to 2.79 at least...

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts. Seems like the visibility part is a separate question to the sphere part. I suggest editing your question down to just one question (by using the [edit] link below it) and asking the other one separately. Thanks.

Comment: I want to hide the spheres and unhide the body, so they are both related to visibility.
Thanks m ardito, I tried to close and reopen, but no change. :( I was able right click on each item (feet, head, etc.) and a menu came up that allowed me to toggle visibility. But I thought it was strange too the eyes disappeared. Maybe something I accidentally clicked (keyboard). I am using 2.78 as I heard that is the version needed to make SIms 4 custom content. Plus following a video course that uses that.
Unfortunately, the little globes are not select-able, so not sure how to get rid of them. :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It was "rig". I'm still a beginner, so not sure what "rig" is exactly, but it's where all my items are for my model. So I right-clicked "rig" and selected "Toggle Visible" and they went away. :)